# How can I get the selected value from a SelectList in a view to the controller without using a form post?

Tags: c#, routes, attributes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to pass the value of the selected option item as a param to my controller. I'm not using a form because my view utilizes a table and it doesn't like a form inside a table. I need to know the companyID, userID, and RoleID in my controller method to do the work. I am getting companyID and userID properly but I don't know how to get the role the user selected.

VIEW:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrationDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            Account Type
        </th>
        <th>
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrationDate)
            </td>

            <td>


<select id="roleList" name="roleList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.message, "ID", "Name"))">
    <option selected="selected" value="">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
    </option>
</select>

<a id="approve" asp-action="Approve" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-roleID="">Approve</a> |
<a asp-action="Reject" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Reject</a>

      @section scripts 
{
    <script>
        $('#approve').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $('#roleList').val();
        if (id > 0) {
            $("#approve").attr('asp-route-roleID').valueOf(id);
        }
        else {
            $('#message').text('select an option first!')
        }
    });
```

CONTROLLER:

```
         [Route("Admin/Approve/{companyID:int}/{id}/{roleID?}")]
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Approve(int companyID, string id, int roleID, Role role)
    {
        //id = await GetCurrentUserId();

        if (id == null || roleID == 0 || companyID == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //return user object from db by Id
            var user = await _context.User.FindAsync(companyID, id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //Update User Status to Approved
            user.Status = UserStatus.APPROVED;
            //Update User Role to Assigned Value
           // user.Role = role;

            //Insert new CompanyRoleUser record 
            CompanyRoleUser crUser = new CompanyRoleUser(user.CompanyID, roleID, user.Id);
            try
            {
                _context.Update(crUser);
                _context.Update(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserExists(user.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
           
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        
        return Redirect("/Admin/Index");
    }
```

UPDATED WITH CODE HELP FROM ANSWER:

```
  <td>
    <select onchange="SetRoleId(this)" id="roleList" name="roleList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.message, "ID", "Name"))">

      <option selected="selected" value="">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)</option>
     </select>

            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="approve" asp-action="Approve" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Approve</a> |
                <a asp-action="Reject" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Reject</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
    function SetRoleId(data) {
        var id = data.value;
        if (id > 0) {
            var url = $(data).next("#approve").attr("href");
            var list = url.split("/");
            var index = list.length;
            if (index < 6) {
                //why is 6
                //the default length of your approve link is 5:"","Admin","Approve","companyID" and "id"
                //you just need to add the roleid to the url ending
                $(data).next("#approve").attr("href", url + "/" + id);
            }
            else {
                //if you want to change the selectlist,the default url length is 6
                //because you have added the roleid before
                var urlstring = "";
                for (var i = 1; i < index - 1; i++) {
                    urlstring = urlstring + "/" + list[i];
                }
                $(data).next("#approve").attr("href", urlstring + "/" + id);
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#message').text('select an option first!')
        }
    };
</script>
}
```

But now when I run it I don't see the href changing in the browser console as I select different Roles in the dropdown. The browser console gives the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"
[Console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE2nr.jpg)

When I click the "Approve" button I don't have the RoleID appended in the url.

I have the standard jquery script tag included in the _layout.cshtml page:

```
  <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all, please take the time to format your code appropriately. Secondly, `asp-route` works **server-side**, you cannot get a client-side value if the page hasn't even been rendered to the client

Comment: The page has been rendered, the roles are rendered in the drop-down. Now I'm trying to send the the selected role value to the controller. Is that not correct.

Comment: No, you need to either subit the form or make an HTTP request using JavaScript

Comment: I'm not using a form because it doesn't like form inside my table. The routing looks like it's working to me except that I'm missing the roleID that was selected in the dropdown. Seems like I could use an ATHtml.ActionLink("Approve", "Admin", new { ATitem.CompanyID, ATitem.Id, }) to send my view parms to the controller for processing. However, I don't know how to get the selected Role out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag helper would generate the `href` in `anchor` when you run the project.So set the tag helper value by js is not possible.You need to set the `href` value.

View:

```
                //....
                <td>
                    <select onchange="SetRoleId(this)" id="roleList" name="roleList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.message, "ID", "Name"))">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
                        </option>
                    </select>

                    <a id="approve" asp-action="Approve" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Approve</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Reject" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Reject</a>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
@section scripts
{
    <script>   
        function SetRoleId(data) {
            var id = data.value;
            if (id > 0) {               
                var url = $(data).next("#approve").attr("href");
                var list = url.split("/");
                var index = list.length;
                if (index < 6) {
                    //why is 6
                    //the default length of your approve link is 5:"","Admin","Approve","companyID" and "id"
                    //you just need to add the roleid to the url ending
                    $(data).next("#approve").attr("href",url+ "/" +id);                                       
                }
                else { 
                   //if you want to change the selectlist,the default url length is 6
                   //because you have added the roleid before
                    var urlstring = ""; 
                    for (var i = 1; i < index - 1; i++) {
                        urlstring = urlstring+ "/" + list[i] ;
                    }
                    $(data).next("#approve").attr("href", urlstring+"/"+id);
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#message').text('select an option first!')
            }                   
        };
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

The reason for you do not work is that we have different razor view.Change your code like below:

```
                <td>
                    <select onchange="SetRoleId(this)" id="roleList" name="roleList" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.message, "ID", "Name"))">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a id="approve" asp-action="Approve" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Approve</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Reject" asp-route-companyID="@item.CompanyID" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Reject</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
@section scripts
{
    <script>   
        function SetRoleId(data) {
            var id = data.value;
            if (id > 0) {
                var element = $(data).parent().next("td").find("#approve");
                var url = element.attr("href");
                var list = url.split("/");
                var index = list.length;
                if (index < 6) {
                    element.attr("href",url+ "/" +id);                                       
                }
                else {
                    var urlstring = ""; 
                    for (var i = 1; i < index - 1; i++) {
                        urlstring = urlstring+ "/" + list[i] ;
                    }
                    element.attr("href", urlstring+"/"+id);
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#message').text('select an option first!')
            }                   
        };
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Please share enough code and the error message screenshot to us.

Comment: I updated the original post with your helpful code. The error in the browser console now is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"